# Remove From List X all content of List Y

Tags: c#, list

I have two list my requirement is I want to create one list whose data should be all value of x  minus all value from y.

For example.

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
List<string> y = new List<string>();

List s contain {“a”,”b”,”c”,”d”}
List y contain {“b”,”c”}
```

I want one to create one more list

```
List<string>  z = new List<string>();
```

Whose value should be

```
{“a”,”d”}
```

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use LinQ:

```
z=s.Except(y).ToList();
```

Here's a reference for your specific problem: [How to: Find the Set Difference Between Two Lists (LINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx)

Comment: Worth mentioning - Except will return unique items - so if list `s` has several `d`, only one will be returned

Answer (score 0):

One approach it would be the following

```
z=s.Where(x=>!y.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
List<string> a = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
List<string> b = new List<string> { "b", "c" };
List<string> c = a.Except(b, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
```